# In which way is height information stored in a DEM?

Tags: qgis, convert, dem

I'm struggling with different DEM data, because I don't know how to convert the height information in meters.

When I load ASTER and SRTM tifs in QGIS, it shows me the spectrum of the grayband (0 to max). All the time I thought I could just take this value and see it as the height of each Point in m. Later I compared the graybandvalues with the actual height of the objects and realised that it's terribly off (German Zugspitze 500m, Test Area Swellendam 600m, a mountain in Malaysia more than 2000m). I tried it with different SRTM and ASTER DEMs, but no one was correct.

I would be very happy, if someone had an idea, how to solve this problem.

Comment: What units are indicated in the metadata?

Comment: Driver
GDAL provider
GTiff
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
D:/GIS/Maps Malaysia/SRTM/srtm_60_11/srtm_60_11.tif
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=3589
STATISTICS_MEAN=257.11711059807
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-37
STATISTICS_STDDEV=347.34420343174
Dimensions
X: 6001 Y: 6001 Bands: 1
Origin
115,10.0004
Pixel Size
0.000833333,-0.000833333
No Data Value
-32768 
Data Type
Int16 - Sixteen bit signed integer 
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

Comment: Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
114.9995839386829175,4.9995834301807909 : 120.0004172720162501,10.0004167635141243
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet 


These are all metadata. I am new with DEMs, so I don't really know what they mean.

Answer (score 3):

After I checked my data source and used different GIS Tools (under them 3DEM a really nice DEM Viever, that gave me the right heights), I came to the conclusion that the grayband values, that are shown by QGIS, when you drag your DEMs in it, are simply wrong and aren't the height values.

Both SRTM and ASTER DEMs store (in general) their data in meter. If you want to get the real height Information in QGIS, you have to use the statistic tools and process the data, the way you want it. Then you will realise, that SRTM data are quite nice to work with.